# Error editing Windows DNS

Tags: powershell, dns, wmi

I've read on several different reliable tech blogs and discussions that the following code should allow me to target my NICs with static IPs that are using specific DNS servers, and update the servers they're using.

```
$NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "DHCPEnabled='FALSE'" |
        Select-Object -Property DNSServerSearchOrder |
        Where {
            $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -contains "OldDNS1" -or
            $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -contains "OldDNS2"
        }

foreach ($NIC in $NICs) {
    $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("NewDNS1","NewDNS2")
}
```

However, when I run that code I get the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject]
doesn't contain a method named 'SetDNSServerSearchOrder'. 
At line:2 char:33
+ $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder <<<< ("NewDNS1","NewDNS2")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetDNSServerSearchOrder:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I haven't been able to figure out or properly find a solution and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: After @FoxDeploy's suggestion I was getting another error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "SetDNSServerSearchOrder" and the argument count: "2".
At line:2 char:33
+ $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder <<<< ("172.16.1.50","172.16.210.53")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I had to change:

```
$NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("NewDNS1","NewDNS2")
```

It is now:

```
$NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($("NewDNS1","NewDNS2"))
```

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `select` statement.

Using `Select-Object` changes an object from it's previous configuration, and makes it into a `System.Management.ManagementObject`, which is basically just a type of PowerShell custom object.

If you remove the `Select-Object` statement, this will work.

```
$NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "DHCPEnabled='FALSE'" |
        Where {
            $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -contains "OldDNS1" -or
            $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -contains "OldDNS2"
        }
```

Comment: The conversion to `PSCustomObject` wouldn't necessarily be a problem, but `SetDNSServerSearchOrder` is a method and can't be "selected" that way since `Select-Object` is only for selecting properties. Essentially the `Select-Object` statement is removing the very method the OP wants to call later on.

Comment: Thanks for the edit help too, I couldn't figure out how to space it here.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Great catch @FoxDeploy